# Angular2 hosting on Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, hosting

I hosted my Angular2 website on Firebase, by following all the necessary steps

```
firebase login

firebase init (single page app replace index.html file YES)(folder public)

firebase deploy
```

But my website consist only of Welcome template (Welcome
Firebase Hosting Setup Complete ect...)

I tried to delete/replace/customise index.html file inside public folder, but Welcome template are still there...

How do I replace this template with my own website??

content of my firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add contents of your `firebase.json`? And  what is the output path of your build?

Comment: I added content of firebase.json, but how can I see my output path on build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hosting` in `firebase.json` points to the wrong directory.
If you do a build, and the target is the `location/of/dist/folder` directory, you need to change `firebase.json` to

```
{ 
    "hosting": { 
        "public": "location/of/dist/folder",       
        "ignore": [ 
            "firebase.json", 
            "**/.*", 
            "**/node_modules/**" ], 
        "rewrites": [ 
            { 
                "source": "**", 
                "destination": "/index.html" 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can check the build target in `.angular-cli.json` (or `angular.json` for V6)
`"outDir": "location/of/dist/folder"` (or `"outputPath": "location/of/dist/folder"` for V6)

Also, if you've build your project before you do `firebase init`. You should have been prompted if `index.html` must be overwritten.

Instead of editing `firebase.json` you can re-run `firebase init`

Comment: Thank you for help, i tried everything (changing firebase.json, re-run firebase init), and still nothing...
Still the same Welcome template

Comment: Have you located your output directory? If you do `ng build`, is the `index.html` that firebase created overwritten?

Comment: I have located my output directory, still nothing.. 

And when I do ng build I get this error:
(node:15328) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null

Comment: you need to be able to build your project. It is the built version that is deployed to firebase. If the build is failing, the `index.html` file is not replaced/created and the default `index.html` file created by `firebase init` is deployed